# Stop function from contributing to type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type like this:

```js
interface Test<R, T> {
    inputType: R;
    transformer: (input: R extends any ? R : never) => T;
}

// simple inference helper function
function inferTest<T extends Test<any, any>>(t: T): T {
    return t;
}
```

What I want is to use the type and function like this:

```js
const test = inferTest({
    inputType: 0,
    transformer: input => String(input)
})
```

Everything should be correctliy typed, i.e. the type of `transformer` should be infered as `(input: number) => string`.

However, my issue is that this inference does not work. `input` is being inferred as `any` (my guess is because I have not given an explicit type). Is there a way to make this work, so that `transformer` will correctly be inferred as `(input: number) => string` and not `(input: any) => string`?

Please note that writing `transformer: (input: number) => String(input)` is not really a solution. This is a minimal example, the type of `inputType` is far more complex to determine in the real use-case.

Comment: This doesn't work because `Test<any, any>` is just `{inputType: any, transformer: (input: any) => any}`; so `T extends Test<any, any>` doesn't constrain `transformer`'s arg type in any way.  The way for this to work is to make `inferTest()` generic in `T` and `R` just like `Test`.  Does that fully address the question? If so then the existing answer is essentially correct (although we might want to edit it to add an explanation).  If not, what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your double-generic type is pretty hard core, not gonna lie. It does seem to be correct, therefore it seems in this case you hit the limit of TypeScript's type inference capabilities.

Is there any way you could rewrite your code to use only one level of generics like this?

```
function inferTest<T, U>(inputType: T, transformer: ((input: T extends any ? T : never) => U)) {
  return {
    inputType,
    transformer,
  };
}

const test = inferTest(0, input => String(input));
```

If so then that's your solution. It works perfectly.